# I cannot find any way to convert multiple jpg or png to gif in vb.net using ffmpeg

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg

Is there anyway i can get multiples png or jpg images to gif using ffmpeg in vb.net
I have start a new application to capture certain frames from a video but now i want to get all the frames extracted in gif image using ffmpeg.
This is my code so far:
I have in fact all ready try like this but not succeed 
I have made some changes and i get the gif file but in empty state
This is my code so far

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Dim video = ""
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg.exe")
Dim frame As Long 'individual frames
Dim tempdir As String = "C:\avitogifconverter\" ' images temp directory
Dim DestPath As String = "C:\avitogifconverter\"
Public Declare Auto Function FindWindowNullClassName Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindow" (ByVal lpClassname As Integer, ByVal lpWindownName As String) As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(tempdir)
    TextBox1.Text = "exp:-->video.avi or webm or flv"
    TextBox1.Clear()



End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim p As Process = Process.Start("cmd", "/k ffmpeg.exe -i " + TextBox1.Text + " -filter:v fps=1/15 C:\avitogifconverter\out%02d.jpg")
    p.WaitForExit()

    If p.HasExited Then
        MsgBox("The Extraction Are Finish...")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Label3.Text = "cmd" + "/k ffmpeg.exe -i " + TextBox1.Text + " -filter:v fps=1/15 C:\avi to gif converter\out%02d.jpg"
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click


    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        'TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        TextBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text <> Nothing Then
        'My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(TextBox1.Text, DestPath)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim args As String 'declare args
    args = " -framerate 1/5 -i C:\avitogifconverter\out%02d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\avitogifconverter\out.gif "
    Dim proc As New Process
    Dim proci As New ProcessStartInfo
    proci.FileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\ffmpeg.exe"
    proci.Arguments = args
    proci.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    proci.CreateNoWindow = True
    proci.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo = proci
    proc.Start()
    Do Until proc.HasExited = True
        Me.Text = "Saving"
    Loop
    Me.Text = "your video done"

    MsgBox("Done")

    'IO.Directory.Delete(tempdir, True)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: if i change the output to avi its work perfect but if i try with gif the gif its come empty

Comment: You're telling `ffmpeg` to use the encoder libx264 to create H.264 video, but trying to use the GIF output format. These are not compatible. You should run each `ffmpeg` command manually, unscripted in command line first. Once you get each one working you can then attempt to script it in VB. Right now you're probably missing the console output that `ffmpeg` provides which usually tells you what you're doing incorrectly.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard in fact i just finish the code i finally discovery what its wrong i jus go post the answer

Answer (score 0):

In fact i just finish the code i finally discovery what its wrong.
This is the working code to convert mp4 to gif
So i have decided to convert first the images to mp4 and the convert the mp4 to gif

I have try to move the file to other location but wen i try to move the file to a different location its say i can not find the directory but the directory exist.
what i have miss here
this is the code

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1
Dim fpsx = 10
Dim video = ""
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg.exe")
Dim frame As Long 'individual frames
Dim tempdir As String = "C:\avitogifconverter\" ' images temp directory
Dim DestPath As String = "C:\avitogifconverter\"
Public Declare Auto Function FindWindowNullClassName Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindow" (ByVal lpClassname As Integer, ByVal lpWindownName As String) As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(tempdir)
    TextBox1.Text = "exp:-->video.avi or webm or flv"
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Text = fpsx


End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    fpsx = TextBox2.Text
    TextBox2.Text = fpsx

    Dim p As Process = Process.Start("cmd", "/k ffmpeg.exe -i " + TextBox1.Text + " -framerate 5/1 -filter:v fps=" + TextBox2.Text + " C:\avitogifconverter\out%02d.jpg")
    p.WaitForExit()

    If p.HasExited Then
        MsgBox("The Extraction Are Finish...")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click


    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        'TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        'TextBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        TextBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Dim newdialog As New OpenFileDialog()
        If newdialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            System.IO.File.Copy(newdialog.FileName, tempdir)
            MessageBox.Show(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(newdialog.FileName) & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(newdialog.FileName))
        End If
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text <> Nothing Then
        'My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(TextBox1.Text, DestPath)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim args As String 'declare args
    args = " -i C:\avitogifconverter\out%02d.jpg -r 10 C:\avitogifconverter\out.gif "
    'args = " -i C:\avitogifconverter\out%02d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\avitogifconverter\out.mp4 "
    Dim proc As New Process
    Dim proci As New ProcessStartInfo
    proci.FileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\ffmpeg.exe"
    proci.Arguments = args
    proci.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    proci.CreateNoWindow = True
    proci.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo = proci
    proc.Start()
    Do Until proc.HasExited = True
        Me.Text = "Saving"
    Loop
    Me.Text = "your video done"

    MsgBox("Done")
    Dim directoryName As String = "C:\avitogifconverter\"
    For Each deleteFile In Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        File.Delete(deleteFile)
    Next

    'IO.Directory.Delete(tempdir, True)
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Form2.Show()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Encoding from images to MP4 to GIF is wasteful and will make it look worse. Why not encode directly from images to GIF (and/or MP4)?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i have google it but i have not see any example to do it from images to gif

Comment: A simple example: `ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i %03d.png output.gif`
A [less simple example](https://superuser.com/a/556031/110524).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Tanks for the great help i have one more thing its not work correct yet is: every thing is ok if i put my video in side of the same folder but if i not put my video in the same folder of the project the ffmpeg its says no such file or directory. wen i click to chose my file with openfiledialog , how can i copy or move my chose video to the correct directory in this case C:\avitogifconverter\

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i have try like this i have edit to put an example

Comment: I'm not a VB user, and this is a problem with your scripting and not a direct issue with `ffmpeg`, so I don't know. Check your paths I guess.